# Is this terrible programming practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

So I've read a bit about using exec in Python now and how it is generally frowned upon. But I thought of this approach to solving this particular problem before I realized the negatives. I finally got my solution working and I was wondering if it really is a bad solution. I was proud of coming up with this answer, and now I need to know if I should go back to the drawing board.

The problem I solved is to come up with a solution of creating a minesweeper grid from a True False array where True is a bomb and False is an empty space. And without further ado, I give you the code:

```
import copy
def minesweeper(matrix):
    output_matrix = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
    flag=0
    for x in range(len(matrix)):
        for y in range(len(matrix[x])):
            # define search areas with a flag
            if x==0:
                flag += 1
            if y==0:
                flag += 2
            if x+1==len(matrix):
                flag += 4
            if y+1==len(matrix[x]):
                flag += 8
            sum_xy = check_around(x,y,flag, matrix)
            print(sum_xy)
            output_matrix[x][y] = sum_xy
            flag=0
    return output_matrix


def check_around(x,y,flag, matrix):
    summ = 0
    _locals = locals()
    operations = ["summ += matrix[x-1][y-1]",
                  "summ += matrix[x-1][y]",
                  "summ += matrix[x-1][y+1]",
                  "summ += matrix[x][y-1]",
                  "summ += matrix[x][y+1]",
                  "summ += matrix[x+1][y-1]",
                  "summ += matrix[x+1][y]",
                  "summ += matrix[x+1][y+1]"]
    # remove corresponding operations from array based on flag value
    if flag&1:
        indices = [i for i in range(len(operations)) if "x-1" in operations[i]]
        for i in reversed(indices):
            del operations[i]
    if flag&2:
        indices = [i for i in range(len(operations)) if "y-1" in operations[i]]
        for i in reversed(indices):
            del operations[i]
    if flag&4:
        indices = [i for i in range(len(operations)) if "x+1" in operations[i]]
        for i in reversed(indices):
            del operations[i]
    if flag&8:
        indices = [i for i in range(len(operations)) if "y+1" in operations[i]]
        for i in reversed(indices):
            del operations[i]
    # print(f"x={x}, y={y}, num operations={len(operations)}")

    for command in operations:
        # print("exec", command)
        exec(command, {}, _locals)
    return _locals["summ"]



matrix = [[True, False, False],
          [False, True, False],
          [False, False, False]]

print(minesweeper(matrix))
```

Thank you very much in advance for taking the time to help me improve!

Comment: Don't feel bad for coming up with this solution. But what you need to grok is that if you want to save a *behavior* don't use strings representing source code, instead, **use functions**

Comment: As for the narrow question of using `exec` itself, its a security risk if you run code from an untrusted source. That isn't the case here.

Comment: [Codereview.se]

Comment: there is [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to let your code be reviewed. Stackoverflow is rather meant to solve coding problems

Comment: Would it be better to use functions in this particular case? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @ChasetheDream yes, that's what I was saying. The problem with `exec` here isn't security, it's that dynamic code execution adds a lot of indirection, making your code harder to maintain, when it doesn't really add anything over using functions.

Comment: And please don't think I'm just trying to be harsh. This is a solution to the problem you were trying to face, and you should be satisfied that you got a solution. However, don't get complacent,  I just want to nudge you towards a better solution. This is how we all learn.